# How do I exclude particular part of code from django_nose coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage, nose

In some rare cases my methods can contain branches of code unreachable during testing (e.g. handling of some rare exceptions etc.)

I mean I have code that I'll never want to cover by tests. Is there a special type of comment/docstring/whatever to mark such code so it is clearly distinguishable from normal code and excluded from nose code coverage reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`coverage` documentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html), you need to put a `pragma: no cover` comment into the code:

> Any line with a comment of “pragma: no cover” is excluded. If that
>   line introduces a clause, for example, an if clause, or a function or
>   class definition, then the entire clause is also excluded.

```
a = my_function1()
if debug:   # pragma: no cover
    msg = "blah blah"
    log_message(msg, a)
b = my_function2()
```

You can also use [`coverage` configuration file](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html) and define [`exclude_lines`](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html#h_Advanced_exclusion) configuration parameter with the list of patterns to exclude from coverage. For example, to exclude all `__repr__()` methods from being taking into account:

```
[report]
exclude_lines = def __repr__
```